# Reporting with Sub Tables

Tags: sql, birt

I have two tables:

| Cert | Type |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | Roof |
| 102 | Sewer |

| Cert | Contact |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | Bob |
| 101 | Tom |
| 101 | Mary |
| 102 | Tom |

They want a report like:

| Cert | Type | Contact1 | Contact2 | Contact3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | Roof | Bob | Tom | Mary |

My tools are SQL and BIRT.  I am really just looking for some direction.  I assume I need to reshape the data but am not sure where to start.

Comment: Can you share your best coding attempt at this problem?

Comment: Also, is there a fixed maximum number of contacts for each type?

Comment: My solution was to only pull the highest id contact which made people happy.      select  cert,type,contact
 from cert 
left outer join contact on contact=cert
and contact=(select max(certid) from contact where contact.cert=cert

Comment: No there is no max, but in this case i could make an assumption of 5, knowing there will always be some outlier.

Comment: Interesting. Now the point is, do you care more about efficiency or about outliers? In the first case, you would lose outliers, in the second case you would retrieve them, but with some performance expenses. @Brian

Answer (score 0):

on MySQL if you do not need variable columns, you could use something like this

```
select 
  table1.cert,
  table1.type,
  group_concat(table2.contact separator ",")
from table1
join table2 on table2.cert=table1.cert
group by 1,2
```

Comment: This answer won't get the requested output in terms of schema.

Comment: At most DB engines you can get additional columns only by multiple JOINs + columns from these JOINs. So, you need exactly to know maximum column count.
Or, you can generate SQL query outside.

Comment: It wouldn't be efficient to carry this task out with multiple joins. You can use one join and apply operators that are usually employed in pivoting tasks. In case the amount of columns is generic, the only way is dynamic sql.

Comment: What DBMS do you use?

Comment: I use DB2, but I am not the admin.  I can make requests of them but the wait time is months+

Comment: Is there a name for this kind of thing?  It has been hard to research without something proper to call it.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use a combination of CTEs (aka WITH clause), group functions and analytic functions in ANSI SQL (assuming that DB2 supports this, I'm using Oracle).

Note 1: Another option is to use a cross tab in BIRT - I'll not explain that here, but you should consider it. The reason why I'm not using it is because it can be quite difficult to adjust the layout then.

The idea is as follows - and you can develop it step by step with pure SQL.

Input:
Some SQL that selects your data as a flat table.

Ouput:
SQL that creates a structure which you can "just output" with a BIRT table item.

The idea is as follows:

Step 1: develop your "basic SQL", e.g. in your case it would have three columns CERT, TYPE, CONTACT.

Step 2: Use analytic functions to assign logical row numbers and column numbers to your data.

eg. you could use
`dense_rank() over (order by CERT) as LOGICAL_ROW`
and
`row_number() over (partition by CERT order by CONTACT) as LOGICAL_COL`

It is important to use the same column in the `partition by` clause for the column number as in the `order by` clause for the row number.

Now you have your 3 columnns from the basic SQL + 2 columns for row and column.

However, since you can only display e.g. 3 columns on the paper physically, you probably need

Step 3: Create physical "sub-matrices" from your logical matrix.
Let's say only 3 columns fit horizontally.

```
WITH
basic_sql as 
( SELECT CERT, TYPE, CONTACT from ... where ...
),
logical_matrix as
(
  select b.*,
         dense_rank() over (order by CERT) as LOGICAL_ROW,
         row_number() over (partition by CERT order by CONTACT) as LOGICAL_COL
  from basic_sql b
)
select
    lm.*,
    mod((logical_col - 1), 3) + 1 as PHYSICAL_COL,
    trunc((logical_col - 1) / 3) + 1 as SUB_MATRIX
from logical_matrix lm
```

Now you have 7 columns (of these, LOGICAL_COL is no longer needed, sprictly speaking).

The final step 4 is the "pivoting" with a SQL GROUP BY:

```
WITH
basic_sql as 
( SELECT CERT, TYPE, CONTACT from ... where ...
),
logical_matrix as
(
  select b.*,
         dense_rank() over (order by CERT) as LOGICAL_ROW,
         row_number() over (partition by CERT order by CONTACT) as LOGICAL_COL
  from basic_sql b
),
sub_matrices as (
    select
        lm.*,
        mod((logical_col - 1), 3) + 1 as PHYSICAL_COL,
        trunc((logical_col - 1) / 3) + 1 as SUB_MATRIX
    from logical_matrix lm
)
select SUB_MATRIX,
       LOGICAL_ROW,
       max(CERT) as CERT,
       max(TYPE) as TYPE,
       max(case when PHYSICAL_COL = 1 then CONTACT end) as CONTACT1,
       max(case when PHYSICAL_COL = 2 then CONTACT end) as CONTACT2,
       max(case when PHYSICAL_COL = 3 then CONTACT end) as CONTACT3
from physical_matrices pm
group by SUB_MATRIX, LOGICAL_ROW
order by SUB_MATRIX, LOGICAL_ROW
```

Note 2: Note how you can develop the SQL step-by-step. With step *n+1*, you use the sql from step *n* as a CTE (common table expression) in the WTIH clause.

Note 3: In modern SQL, you might also consider the SQL PIVOT clause. However, the concept that I'm showing here is more flexible.

Note 4: If you also need dynamic column headers, you can compute them similar to the cell values CONTACT1,2,3, but you'll need an additional MAX(..) `analytic` function to avoid empty column headers.